# How to pass parameter to azure pipeline using python script, API

Tags: python, azure, api

I have a script in python which triggers pipeline build using API.
I need to figure out how to pass parameter to this pipeline.

this script below runs pipeline with id 3023 and returns status 200:

```
def run_pipeline(PAT):
    url="[organization_url]_apis/pipelines/[pipeline_id]/runs?api-version=6.0-preview.1"
    headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"}
    data={
        'id': '3023'
        }
    request_run_pipeline = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=data, auth = ('',PAT),verify = False)

    return(print(request_run_pipeline.status_code))
```

now, my test pipeline with a parameter looks like this:

```
parameters:
  - name: text
    type: string
    default: test pipeline

trigger:
      branches:
        include:
        - main

steps:
  - script: echo ${{ parameters.text }}
    displayName: 'run one-line script - write text'
```

I need to somehow pass this "text" parameter using my python script, no idea how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I created one Azure DevOps pipeline with your yaml script like below:-

```yaml
- main

  

pool:

vmImage: ubuntu-latest

  

parameters:

- name: text

type: string

default: test pipeline

  

steps:

- script: echo Hello, world!

displayName: 'Run a one-line script'

  

- script: |

echo Add other tasks to build, test, and deploy your project.

echo See https://aka.ms/yaml

displayName: 'Run a multi-line script'

- script: echo ${{ parameters.text }}

displayName:'run one-line script - write text'
```

**Output:-**

[image]

[image]

I tried the below python code to trigger the pipeline by passing the text parameter like below:-

```py
import  json

import  requests

  

def  run_pipeline(PAT, project_name, pipeline_id, parameter_value):

url = f"https://dev.azure.com/organization-name/{project_name}/_apis/pipelines/{pipeline_id}/runs?api-version=6.0-preview.1"

headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"}

data = {

"templateParameters": json.dumps({"text": parameter_value}),

"pipelineId": pipeline_id

}

request_run_pipeline = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=data, auth=('', PAT), verify=False)

return  request_run_pipeline.status_code

  

# Example usage

PAT = "<pat-token>"

project_name = "<project-name>"

pipeline_id = "22"

parameter_value = "test pipeline"

  

run_pipeline(PAT, project_name, pipeline_id, parameter_value)
```

The code ran successfully and the Pipeline was triggered like below:-

**Output:-**

[image]

[image]

[image]